# flutter project merge into GitHub fails

Tags: flutter, github, merge

I have a flutter project on my Windows pc. I have connected it to GitHub but when I try to merge files to my repository I get this error:

Untracked Files Prevent Merge
Move or commit them before Merge

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you need to commit all changes you did before. If you don't do that it can get difficult after a merge.

In your IDE should be a button like in VS-Code which you can use to commit the files. Otherwise, type `git add -A` and then `git commit` in the console to commit every change to your GitHub repository.